# How can I prevent a client-side data rule workflow from being executed the first time the screen loads?

Tags: aviarc

The problem I have is this: I have a data rule which validates a field against a regex. I've provided both server- and client-side versions of the data rule, and bound them to appropriate dataset events.

The problem is, when I load the screen which contains the record creation form, the field is marked as invalid before the user gets any opportunity to even enter a value. I assume it's something to do with the dataset field being initially bound to the text-edit widget. I only want the validity to be test after the user enters a value, or when the screen is submitted.

How can I prevent the data rule from running when the screen is first loaded?

**Update**

Here's is my data rule definition:

```xml
<data-rule name="{@name}"
           factory-class="com.aviarc.framework.datarule.xml.DefaultXMLDataRuleProviderFactoryImpl"
           datarule-class="com.aviarc.framework.datarule.workflow.WorkflowDataRule">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="field" mandatory="y" type="field"/>
        <attribute name="valid-membership-number-regex" default="\d{8}[a-zA-Z\d]" mandatory="n" type="string">
            Valid membership number regex:

            - \d{8}   : match 8 digits
            - [a-zA-Z\d] : match any alphanumeric character
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
    <event name="onRowFieldChanged" workflow="workflows/set-membership-number-valid"/>
    <event name="onCurrentRowFieldChanged" client-action="actions/set-membership-number-valid"/>
</data-rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For field-change events like the ones I'm using, you need explicitly pass through the field that the dataset is bound to, like so:

```xml
<event name="onRowFieldChanged" field="{@field}" .../>
<event name="onCurrentRowFieldChanged" field="{@field}" .../>
```

I think my data rule must have been executing on *any* field change event, rather than just the field it was bound to.